# Algorithm for matching data

Tags: algorithm, string, string-matching

I have a project where I am testing a device that is very sensitive to noise (electromagnetic, radio, etc...).  The device generates 5-6 bytes per second of binary data (looks like gibberish to an untrained eye) based on a give input (audio).

Depending on noise, sometime the device will miss characters, sometimes it will insert random characters, sometimes multiples of both.

I have written an app that gives the user an ability to see on the fly the errors that it generates (as compared to the master file [e.g. what the device should output in ideal conditions]).  My algorithm basically takes each byte in the live data and compares it to the byte in the same position in the known master file. If the bytes don't match, I have a window of 10 characters both ways from the current position, where I'll seek a match nearby.  If that matches (plus a validation or two), I visually mark up the location in the UI and register an error.

This approach works reasonably well and actually, given the speed of the incoming data, works real time as well. However, I feel like what I am doing is not optimal and the approach would fall apart if the data would stream at higher rates.

Are there other approaches I could take?  Are there known algorithms for this type of thing?
I read many years ago that NASA's data collection outfit (e.g. ones that communicate with crafts in space and on the Moon/Mars) have had a 0.00001% loss of data despite tremendous interference in space.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume of main interest is the signal generated by the device? What is more important? Detecting when an error has occurred or making the signal 'robust' against such errors? I do a lot of signal processing lately and denoising a signal is part of my routine, I'm basically trying to estimate the real signal and remove any contaminants.

I don't know how the signal generated by the device is further used...if it's being recorded to a computer, then you can easily apply some denoising, try wavelet denoising for instance. You will find packages for doing this in several languages of your choice.